# [vecarrow]{svmono} fails

Tags: math-mode, accents, sv-classes

The documentation of svmono v5.6 from http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/rights-permissions-licensing/manuscript-preparation/5636 says in refguide.pdf:

> vecarrow depicts vectors with an arrow above when \vec-command is used

However, running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass[vecarrow]{svmono}% v5.6 from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/v10
\begin{document}
\(C\vec{C}\)
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: compilation results]

No arrow is printed.
Any bugfix, ideally by means of `\patchcmd` or similar so that I don't have to hack `svmono`? I cannot get myself through to Springer (my e-mails got rejected on the SMTP level).

An excerpt from the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.8.21)  9 AUG 2019 21:12
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
Document Class: svmono 2018/06/25 v5.6
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
File: x11nam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to Unix/X11 (UK)
Package: ntheorem 2011/08/15 1.33
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <8.5> not available
(Font)              size <8> substituted on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.
```

Crosspost:
http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32738

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine with TeXLive 2018. The expected arrow is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class (version 5.6) has

```latex
\DeclareOption{vecarrow}{\def\vec@style{arrow}}
```

and then

```latex
\def\fig@type{arrow}% temporarily abused
\AtBeginDocument{\ifx\vec@style\fig@type\else
\@ifundefined{vec@style}{%
 \def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}}}%
}
{\def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}}%
}
\fi}
```

However, the same class later does

```latex
\def\fig@type{figure}
```

with the consequence that, at begin document, the test `\ifx\vec@style\fig@type` returns false.

Version 5.5 didn't have `\AtBeginDocument` and the test didn't fail.

It's clearly a bug.

You can fix it by redefining `\vec`:

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\vec\relax
  \DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E}%
}

\begin{document}

\(C\vec{C}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `amsmath`, the workaround is different.

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\vec{\protect\mathaccentV{vec}17E}%
}

\begin{document}

\(C\vec{C}\)

\end{document}
```

With `newtxmath` the workaround is different again:

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\vec{\protect\mathaccentV{vec}2AE}%
}

\begin{document}

\(C\vec{C}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MdAyq6 No, but I added the workaround; `mathtools` or just `amsmath` is the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried sending a bug report.